# How to generate table with more than 5 conditions

Tags: php, algorithm, mysqli, html-table

## Short

Generating table with barcodes of items. Each item has exact quantity in database table. Fields in tables are limited: 65, if more then 65 then build a second table, then a third one...How to generate tables with this conditions?

[image]

## Detailed

Let's say we want to generate a table with 65 available fields (5x13).

My plan is the following

1. User selects items' checkboxes
2. When user submits form, PHP gets values of checked checkboxes
3. PHP gets quantities of each item from database
4. Generating table

For ex. the quantity for item id 55 is 2 and for 56 is 4 then the table must look like that

[image]

My code looks like that (I know that it's wrong, but I can't figure out how it must be. There must be more than 5 counters: rows counter, columns counter, $_POST['id'] counter, items' quantity counter, table counter (if total sum is more than 65))

## UPDATE

```
    <?php
            $items = array();
            foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `qt` FROM `items` WHERE `id`=?");
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($qt);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->close();
                for ($cnt = 1; $cnt <= $qt; $cnt++)
                    $items[] = $id;
            }
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $item['quantity']; $j++) {

                    // check if it's the beginning of a new table
                    if ($i % 65 == 0)
                        echo '<table>';

                    // check if it's the beginning of a new row
                    if ($i % 5 == 0)
                        echo '<tr>';

                    echo '<td><img src="bc.php?id=' . $item['id'] . '" alt="' . $item['name'] . '" /></td>';

                    // check if it's the end of a row
                    if (($i - 1) % 5 == 0)
                        echo '</tr>';

                    // check if it's the end of a table
                    if (($i - 1) % 65 == 0)
                        echo '</tr></table>';

                    $i++;
                }
            }

// if the last row wasn't closed, close it
            if ($i % 5 != 0)
                echo '</tr>';

// if the last table wasn't closed, close it
            if ($i % 65 != 0)
                echo '</table>';
            ?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a very weird question :) I THINK I get what you're asking, but why do it that way? Why not put it this way: Record1=ItemID(55),ItemCount(2) ; Record2=ItemID(56),ItemCount(4)?

Comment: +1 for the graphics explaining what you want clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT 4

```
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `qt` FROM `items` WHERE `id`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($qt);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    for ($cnt = 1; $cnt <= $qt; $cnt++) {
        // check if it's the beginning of a new table
        if ($i % 65 == 0)
            echo '<table>';

        // check if it's the beginning of a new row
        if ($i % 5 == 0)
            echo '<tr>';

        echo sprintf('<td><img src="bc.php?id=%1$d" alt="%1$d" /></td>', $id);

        // check if it's the end of a row
        if (($i + 1) % 5 == 0)
            echo '</tr>';

        // check if it's the end of a table
        if (($i + 1) % 65 == 0)
            echo '</table>';

        $i++;
    }
}

// if the last table isn't full, print the remaining cells
if ($i % 65 != 0) {
    for ($j = $i%65; $j < 65; $j++) {
        if ($j % 65 == 0) echo '<table>';
        if ($j %  5 == 0) echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        if (($j + 1) %  5 == 0) echo '</tr>';
        if (($j + 1) % 65 == 0) echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What about each item's quantity?

Comment: I'd first put all of the items in the `$items` array - as many times as is the required quantity.

Comment: I mean, let's say, in db table we found that for item id 55  quantity is is 2 and for 56 is 4. What to do next?

Comment: @trl13, of course, you could also do it with two loops - see the second part of my editted answer.

Comment: Please check updated question (code). I think it's true, right?

Comment: @trl13, see my updated post with yet another solution (based on your updated code) ;)

Comment: @trl13, my mistake, there should be `$i+1` in some parts of the code instead of `$i-1`. That should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Yes. Take a look http://prntscr.com/5rkq1 item id 55 and 41's quantities are same - 5. They must be at the top of the page. Not at the center. I mean empty 65-10 =55 cells must be generated any way. Can we modify the code this way?

Comment: man please make last modification, I'm going to select your answer. How to generate all left cells too? I mean if 20 cell's  generated with barcode, generate 65-20=45 more empty cells to fill paper

Comment: @trl13, you just need to modify the closing statements - that is make the table full if it's not. See my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just repeatedly make sheets of 65 cell tables until you're done.
I'm going to pseudo code:

```
data rows = resultOfMyQuery();
int index = 0;
while(index < rows.count()) {
 index = createASheet(rows, index);
}
END;

int createASheet(data rows, int index) {
  int availableCells = 65;
  int column = 0;
  print("<table>");
  while (availableCells > 0) {
    if (index < rows.count()) {
      data row = rows.get(index);
      int quantity = row.getQuantity();
      if (quantity > availableCells) {
        // Stay on this item with reduced quantity for next sheet.
        row.setQuantity(quantity - availableCells);
        rows.set(index, row);
      } else {
        // Move on to next item on this (or next) sheet.
        index++;
      }
      for (i=0; i<quantity && availableCells>0; quantity--) {
        column = makeACell(column, StringFormat("<TAG ATTRIB='%d'></TAG>",row.getId()));
        availableCells--;
      }
    } else {
      // fill in empty cells
      column = makeACell(column, "");
      availableCells--;
    }
  }
  print("</table>");
  return index;
}

int makeACell(int column, String filling) {
  String cell = "";
  if (column == 0) {
    cell.append("<tr>");
  }
  cell.append("<td>").append(filling).append("</td>");
  if (column == 4) {
    cell.append("</tr>");
  }
  print cell;
  return (column+1) % 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an existing barcode system like QR-codes? These standards offer libraries to build the codes and are readable by various devices.

If you really want to built your own barcode I strongly suggest to use the binary system to store your values. Think about check sums too.